# Trying to implement multiTouch in Swift+Spritekit by binding touch to Sprite but gets warnings I don't understand how to solve

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, multi-touch, subclassing

I am trying to bind the touches to a specific sprite. I have done similar in Objective-C and there this worked fine.

I am getting the following errors
in GameScene class: Class "GameScene" has no initializer
in AnimalSprite class init method: Extra argument 'texture' in call

I tried to google this but can't really solve it. Any ideas?
My ViewController is the default SpriteKit template one. Haven't touched it.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    private var draggedNode: DraggableSprite

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: view.frame);
        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.greenColor()
        self.physicsWorld.gravity.dy = 0

        let animalSpawner = AnimalSpawner()
        self.addChild(animalSpawner)
        animalSpawner.startSpawning()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        /* Called when a touch begins */
        let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)
        if !(touchedNode is AnimalSprite){ return; }

        // Bind touch
        let animalNode = touchedNode as! AnimalSprite
        animalNode.bindTouch(touch)
        self.draggedNode = animalNode
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
        self.draggedNode.unbindTouchIfNeeded(touch)
    }

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
        /* Called before each frame is rendered */
        self.draggedNode.drag()
    }

}

class DraggableSprite: SKSpriteNode {
    var touch: UITouch?
    private var touchOffset = CGPoint()
    private var isDragged: Bool? {
        get{
            if self.touch != nil {
                return true
            }
            return nil
        }
        set{ self.isDragged = newValue }
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func bindTouch(touch: UITouch) {
        self.touch = touch
        let touchLocation = touch.locationInNode(self.parent)
        self.touchOffset = subtractVector(touchLocation, other: self.position)
    }

    func unbindTouchIfNeeded(touch: UITouch){
        if self.touch != touch {

        } else {
            self.touch = nil
        }
    }

    func drag(){
        if (self.touch == nil) { return; }
        let touchLocation = self.touch!.locationInNode(self.parent)
        self.position = subtractVector(touchLocation, other: self.touchOffset)
    }

    //MARK: Private methods
    private func subtractVector(p1: CGPoint, other: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPointMake(p1.x - other.x, p1.y - other.y)
    }

}

class AnimalSprite: DraggableSprite {

    private let animalSize = CGSizeMake(200.0, 200.0)
    private let baseDuration: CGFloat = 10
    private let baseAlpha: CGFloat = 1
    var animalType = Type()
    var isTouched = Bool()

    // Sounds
    ..

    init(){
        super.init(texture: nil, color: nil, size: animalSize)
        self.texture = randomAnimal()
        self.runAction(SKAction.rotateToAngle(0.15, duration: 0.01))
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func randomAnimal() -> SKTexture {
        // Here random animal textture will be returned
        let animalArray = ["cow", "pig", "chicken"]
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(animalArray.count)))
        let animalType = animalArray[randomIndex]
        switch (animalType){
            case "cow":
                self.animalType = Type.Cow
                audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: cowSound, error: nil)
            case "chicken":
                self.animalType = Type.Chicken
                audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: chickenSound, error: nil)
            case "pig":
                self.animalType = Type.Pig
                audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: pigSound, error: nil)
            default:
                self.animalType = Type()
        }
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        return SKTexture(imageNamed: animalArray[randomIndex])
    }

    private func wiggle() -> SKAction {
        let rotateLeft = SKAction.rotateByAngle(-0.3, duration: 0.2)
        let rotateRight = SKAction.rotateByAngle(0.3, duration: 0.2)
        let wiggleSequence = SKAction.sequence([rotateLeft, rotateRight])
        let repeatForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(wiggleSequence)
        return repeatForever
    }

    // MARK: Actions
    func startMove() {
        if let gameScene = self.scene {

            let destinationX = (self.position.x > gameScene.frame.width/2) ? -self.frame.width : gameScene.frame.width+self.frame.width //0 - CGRectGetWidth(gameScene.frame) - animalSize.width
            let destinationY = self.position.y //CGFloat(arc4random_uniform( UInt32(gameScene.size.height)))
            let duration = NSTimeInterval(baseDuration + CGFloat(Double(arc4random_uniform(10)) / 10.0))

            let travel = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(destinationX, destinationY), duration: duration)
            let remove = SKAction.removeFromParent()
            let wiggle = self.wiggle()
            let groupAction = [SKAction .group([travel, wiggle])]
            let sequence = SKAction.sequence([groupAction,  remove])

            println("dest x: \(destinationX) dest y: \(destinationY)")
            self.runAction(sequence, withKey: "moving")
        }
    }

    func playSound() {
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: On which lines are you getting those errors?

Comment: on Class "GameScene" line I get "has no initializer"
and in AnimalSprite class init method: Extra argument 'texture' in call

Answer (score 0):

In your GameScene Class, you are missing an init function. Init functions are mandatory for all classes and you need to make sure you call `super.init()` as well.

```
 override init(size: CGSize) {
    super.init()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your `GameScene` is you've defined a property, `draggedNode`, but you haven't given it a default value or initialised it in an `init` method; therefore Xcode is complaining at you. If it doesn't make sense for `draggedNode` to have a value before the user has pressed the screen, you should make `draggedNode` and optional, like so:

```
private var draggedNode: DraggableSprite?
```

You could then set draggedNode to a value in `touchesBegan` and back to `nil` in `touchesEnded` or `touchesCancelled`.

---

Which is the **exact** line you're having a problem with `AnimalSprite` on? I can update my answer once I know.

---

One more thing I noted looking at your code: in my opinion, it makes more sense to declare `subtractVector` as a global function since it's not specific to your `GameScene` and doing so will enable you to use that code again in other scenes. Taking this one step further, you could override the `-` operator instead of using a function, for example:

```
func - (lhs: CGPoint, rhs: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: lhs.x - rhs.x, y: lhs.y - rhs.y)
}
```